# What's the standard reference to learn about asymptotic expansions?

Tags: reference-request

What's the standard reference to learn about asymptotic expansions as applied to physics ?

Comment: I know Bender & Orszag `Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers: Asymptotic Methods and Perturbation Theory'